# No handler found for uri [/<index>/<type>/] and method [PUT]

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to make a raw NodeJS http request to my elasticsearch index using the insert document api's auto increment id feature.

So this works with `curl`:

`curl -XPOST http://host:3333/catalog/products -d '{ "hello": "world" }'`

But when I try the same in nodejs via this:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  protocol: 'http:',
  mehtod: 'PUT',
  hostname: 'host',
  port: 3333,
  path: '/catalog/products/'
}

http.request(options, ...);
```

It returns this error:

`No handler found for uri [/catalog/products/] and method [PUT]`

However if I add an `id` to the end of that path it will work. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The problem here is the way `POST` and `PUT` works, when you use `POST`, `_id` is optional, ES will generate a unique `_id` for you every time.

Here you are using `PUT` so `_id` is **required**, ES will either create a new document with that id or it will update the document with that id if it exists. You can read [more](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/create-doc.html) about this.

Try indexing with `POST` request as you did with `curl` if you dont want to specify id

```
var options = {
  protocol: 'http:',
  hostname: 'host',
  port: 3333,
  path: '/catalog/products/',
  method: 'POST'                  <--- specify method
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks like I've been working at this too long! Thanks for the info!