# Elastic Search Bad Request - No handler found for uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I am trying to setup a new production server for a project but i have problems at configuring elasticsearch. When I try to make an import for a model from the rails console i get (***-> grayed out):

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] No handler found for uri [//***/***/_bulk?type=***] and method [POST]
from /***/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.12/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:135:in `__raise_transport_error'
from /***/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.12/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:227:in `perform_request'
from /***/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.12/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_re
```

My initializer file looks like:

```
config = {
  host: 'http://localhost:9200/',
  transport_options: {
  request: { timeout: 5 }
}
}
if File.exist?('config/elasticsearch.yml')
  config.merge!     (YAML.load_file('config/elasticsearch.yml').symbolize_keys)
end

Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(config)
```

I use Elasticsearch version 5.3.0

Comment: Maybe this question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025401/no-handler-found-for-uri-index-type-and-method-put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best way to go, but after a lot of time checking out what the problem is, I switched to an earlier version.

Now I use ES 2.3.1 and everything works fine